# WCF Debug with NUnit

Tags: wcf, nunit, visual-studio-2012

Question:  How can I debug a WCF service - I can't hit the breakpoint inside the service

Using VS2012 and NUnit/TestDriven

I can run my test fine, as long as I've started the service before eg Ctrl F5 on the WcfHostApplication.  Am hosting inside Visual Studio.

Have tried putting in a Web.Config into the WcfHostConsoleApplication and setting debug to true.
[image]

This sample app came from [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?gl=GB&v=Dn7ollDhbe4)

```
    //hack to get working as we're not using wsdl yet...mimicking what happens in wsdl
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://www.programgood.net/examples/2012/09/wcf")]
public interface IHelloWcfService
{
    [OperationContract]
    string SayHello(string msg);
}

namespace HelloWcfTests
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class HelloWcfServiceLibrary_Tests
    {
        [Test]
        public void SayHello_GivenHello_ShouldReturn()
        {
            //in reality add Service Ref.. using another special interface called IMetaDataExchange
            IHelloWcfService proxy = ChannelFactory<IHelloWcfService>.CreateChannel(
                new NetTcpBinding(),
                new EndpointAddress("net.tcp://localhost:9000/HelloWcfEndPoint"));

            string msg = "hello";
            string result = proxy.SayHello(msg);
            StringAssert.StartsWith("You entered: hello", result);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not start your service with Ctrl+F5 because it will start your service without debug.

Start it with F5.

[image: debug]

Comment: Start the Host service using F5.  Then go to your test code and right click inside the test, TestDriven.NET start using debugger.  And it works!